# If $f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}f\left(\frac{\lambda^2x}{3}\right)d\lambda,x>0$ and $f(1)=\sqrt3$ and if $f(\alpha)=6$ . find $\alpha$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, implicit-differentiation

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function satisfying $$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}f\left(\frac{\lambda^2x}{3}\right)d\lambda,x>0$$
and $f(1)=\sqrt3$ .

If $y=f(x)$ passes through the point $(\alpha,6)$ then determine the value of $\alpha$ .

**My Attempt**

Since $f(1)=\sqrt3$ we have $\int_{0}^{\sqrt3}f(\frac{\lambda^2}{3})d\lambda=\frac{3}{2}$ and since $f(\alpha)=6$ we have $\int_{0}^{\sqrt3}f(\frac{\lambda^2\alpha}{3})d\lambda=3\sqrt3$.

Also it is given that $f(x)$ is differentiable so $f'(x)=\frac{2}{3\sqrt3}\int_{0}^\sqrt3f'(\frac{\lambda^2x}{3})\lambda^2d\lambda$.

After this I am not able to proceed.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: I was editing an answer while someone is quicker, the rough idea is to use change of variable to get something like $\sqrt{x}f(x) = \int_0^x f(u)/ \sqrt{u} du$, then use fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}f\left(\frac{\lambda^2x}{3}\right)d\lambda\overset{\frac{\lambda^2x}{3}\to \lambda}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_{0}^{x}f(\lambda)\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}d\lambda$$
and hence
$$ (\sqrt xf(x))'=f(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}f(x)}{x}. $$
So
$$ \frac{(\sqrt xf(x))'}{\sqrt{x}f(x)}=\frac1x$$
or
$$\ln(\sqrt{x}f(x))=\ln x+C$$
or
$$ \sqrt{x}f(x)=Cx $$
or $f(x)=C\sqrt x$. By $f(1)=\sqrt3$, one has $C=\sqrt3$ and hence
$$ f(x)=\sqrt{3x}. $$

Comment: What Wolfram does mean when face  to the equation
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}f\left(\frac{\lambda^2x}{3}\right)d\lambda$$ gives as **solution of the recurrence equation**
$$f(x)=\displaystyle {c_12^{\frac{1-\log(x)}{\log(t/3)}}}$$ where $c_1$ is an arbitrary parameter?

Comment: Sometimes Wolfram doesn't give correct answers.